# How to fix Kaminari paginate error in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

When I use Kaminari gem with the code:

Model:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.page(params[:page])
end
```

And use it in index.html.erb:

It prints the next error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<#<Class:0x000000029bbd68>:0x000000029b3dc0>
```

red line on `<%= paginate @posts %>`.

How can I fix this problem? Is my @posts paginable? I think yes.

Comment: How are you including the gem?

Comment: @TMP in Gemfile `gem 'Kaminari'` and `gem install Kaminari`

Comment: Looking at your related questions with running the gem `will_paginate`, I'd say it's definitely related to your initialization or how you're restarting the server.

Comment: did you try turning it on and off again ? :P

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in the Gemfile, then you just need to run `bundle install` instead of `gem install Kaminari`. I would then restart my rails server to ensure its initializers are run to properly require its files.

Comment: Did you try it where Kaminari is lowercase?

Comment: I can't really think of anything else, other gems could conflict, but it shouldn't give you that specific error. It looks like its just not being required, but rails should do that automatically if you have it setup correctly. Maybe you have a Kaminiri.config that is breaking something or something else is messing with the require

Comment: I'm just saying I'm not sure what it is. Kaminari works in my project and all that was necessary was adding it to the Gemfile, bundle installing, and then restarting the server. Sorry i couldn't help. If your code is on Github, I could check it out more thoroughly

Comment: That code is probably fine, it would likely be related to the initialization code. Also, are you two different users?

Comment: Hey! It works in development mode now, but not in production mode. What is the problem? I restarted unicorn and nginx